# What is this glow over some players' weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2

When watching some gameplay videos, I noticed that a green/purple glow will occasionally pass over the player's weapon.

What is this? I don't remember any special weapons with a glow effect, just unusual weapons from Gun Mettle. It doesn't happen on my weapons, so is it a special item?

Comment: +1, happens on my items too, they aren't special items. I wonder why though.

Comment: Can you link the videos? It sounds like a killstreak effect, especially if it's the same every time at a regular interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glow effect is known as a **sheen**, and is visible on weapons which have had a *Specialized Killstreak Kit* applied to them.

From the [wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit#Specialized_Killstreak_Kit) (Two Cities link also added for context/further reading):

> The next tier of Killstreak Kits. In addition to a kill counter, a Specialized Kit also applies a colored sheen to the weapon. As the player's streak increases, the sheen becomes more intense. Specialized Kits are obtained by completing [Specialized Killstreak Kit Fabricators](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit_Fabricator#Specialized_Killstreak_Kit_Fabricator), which can be found as a random reward from completing [Operation Two Cities](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Tour_of_Duty#Available_Tours_of_Duty).
>
> The following sheen colors are available:
>
> - Team Shine (red or blue, matching the player's team)
> - Hot Rod (pink)
> - Manndarin (orange)
> - Deadly Daffodil (yellow)
> - Mean Green (yellowish-green)
> - Agonizing Emerald (blueish-green)
> - Villainous Violet (purple)

[*Professional* kits](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit#Professional_Killstreak_Kit) also include the sheen (and the kill counter from any kind of kit) along with a special effect placed on the character model's eyes.